# PHP assembly metadata of exe file

Tags: php

I have an .exe file on my server, and it has a "File version : 1.0.2.4" in details, in file properties. Is there a way for PHP to retrieve that information?

An equivalent of the following C# code:

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("file.exe");
            version = versionInfo.ProductVersion;
```